# Another way to say a very detailed plan

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I do not want to use "a very detailed plan" would this work?

> I **do have a very detailed plan** for what I want to accomplish and working in the lab is on the top of the list.

or

> I **do have a well planned map** for what I want to accomplish and working in the lab is on the top of the list.

Comment: If something is "***at*** the top of the list" it implies that you don't actually have a very detailed plan yet but a set of objectives, or methods. Moreover is "working in the lab" an accomplishment? Is your aim to be "working in a lab" or would that enable your *actual* goal?

Comment: ***An itemized plan*** could be used here. Though not a map. Is this project mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two words that you could use are:

> 1) a roadmap

defined by [American Heritage Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/roadmap) as "a set of guidelines, instructions, plans, or explanations". A set of something presupposes that someone has worked out many different components, and we no longer have a plan that is too vague or general.

or

> 2) a blueprint

[defined](http://thefreedictionary.com/blueprint) by the same dictionary as "a detailed plan of action".

We speak of roadmaps usually when we have a sequence of steps that come one after the other and have variations for what actions to take in case of various "what ifs" (contingencies). A roadmap describes a process that takes us to our desired outcome.

"Blueprint" does not have this connotation of "various roads to take if something happens". It is simply a very comprehensive, detailed description of how something should look when we have finished the process, e. g. as used here: ["A Blueprint for Transforming Career and Technical Education"](http://www.p12.nysed.gov/cte/docs/PerkinblueprintFull2013.pdf) by the U. S. Department of Education.